# Create Shadow when scrolling in application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

[image]

---

when i scrolling i an see this shadow on the screen

---

[image]

---

How can I implement this part in my App?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html - you'll want to look at adding the elevation at run time when you `scroll`

Comment: May you explain more? @ElliotM